# Incomplete, model-complete theories

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

This is one of two mildly related [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315764/450247).

When $T$ is an incomplete theory with quantifier elimination, the completions of $T$ are determined by the 'characteristic' of the models (i.e. the theory of the substructure generated by $0$).

Is it possible to describe what determine the completions of a theory with model-completeness? (Sometimes it is the set of $\exists$-definable elements, but it may not be true in general.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your statement about theories with QE is true is that in a theory $T$ with QE, every sentence is equivalent to a quantifier-free sentence, so picking a completion of $T$ amounts to deciding the truth value of all the quantifier-free sentences. Semantically speaking, this amounts to describing the substructure generated by the empty set.

[Strictly, for the above statement to be true in a language without constant symbols, we have to admit empty structures (in order to have a substructure generated by the empty set), as well as the basic logical symbols $\top$ and $\bot$ (in order to have any quantifier-free sentences at all). In such a language, case every theory with quantifier elimination must be complete. I feel strongly that these conventions are the correct ones.]

Now if $T$ is a model complete theory, every sentence is equivalent to a universal sentence, so picking a completion $T'$ of $T$ amounts to deciding the truth value of all the universal sentences (and their negations, the existential sentences). The set $T'_\forall$ of all universal consequences of $T'$ is the theory of all substructures of models of $T'$, so this is equivalent on the semantic side to specifying the class of structures which appear as substructures of models of $T'$.

Since the class of models of a universal theory is always closed under directed colimits, and every $L$-structure is a directed colimit of finitely generated substructures, this is further equivalent to specifying the class of finitely generated substructures of models of $T'$. To put it another way, an existential sentence $\exists \overline{x}\, \varphi(\overline{x})$ contains information about a finite piece of the diagram of the substructure generated by the finite tuple $\overline{x}$, and a finitely generated structure is a substructure of a model of $T'$ if and only if every finite piece of its diagram is represented in $T'_\exists$ in this way.

I think this condition about specifying a class of allowable finitely generated structures is the natural generalization of the situation under QE, where you just specify a single $0$-generated structure.

Comment: I do not quite understand your second last sentence: [Semantically speaking, etc....] Why *finitely* generated? (You may need more than one existential sentence to complete $T$.) Should not they also *model* $T$? What if $T$ ha *no* finitely generated model at all?

Comment: "Should not they also *model* $T$?" No! No more than the substructure generated by the empty set should be a model of $T$ when $T$ has QE. I've made a large edit to my answer, in an effort to make it clearer for you. Let me know if I succeeded.

Comment: The edit is worth it. Thank you.